# Removing mass-assignment from worker in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, mass-assignment

I have a worker :

```
module A
 class B
  @queue = :a_b
  def self.perform(*args)
    ...............
    city = City.where(:country_id => 1).first
    city.update_attributes(name: "Delhi", continent: "Asia") //mass-assignment here
    ...............
  end
 end
end
```

I don't have `attr_accessible :name, :continent` in `city.rb`. How should I remove this mass-assignment from the worker?

Comment: I you're using rails 4 you don't have to worry about `attr_accessible` and mass assignment anymore. Instead, you need to use the new [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) feature.

Comment: I don't really see this as mass assignment. You're stating which keys are allowed through. If it were `city.update_attributes(params)` it would be a potential security issue.

Comment: How do I use strong params in a worker?

Answer (score 1):

check the link https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters about how to use strong parameter out of controller.

```
raw_parameters = { :email => "john@example.com", :name => "John", :admin => true }
parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_parameters)
user = User.create(parameters.permit(:name, :email))
```